# Formatting a calculation field number

Tags: cognito-forms

I have two date fields with a calculation field to determine the total days between the two, using the code:

```
= (DepartureDate-ArrivalDate).TotalDays
```

The calculation field is a number type, but the result always shows a decimal result and I can't find a way to force it to be a whole number. I've tried the `Int32.Parse` method but it doesn't change anything. Giving the field a Text type works okay, but then I can't use the result in another calculation further down the form.

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to add an additional calculation field to represent the numeric value that is set to Show This Field - Never.  This field will only be available in calculations, so will not affect the layout of your form.